# How to use the write function in python 3.5.2 and search for the file I want to accurately?

Tags: python

I have a python program that looks like this:

```
fileName = input("What file do you want to target?(add file type i.e. 
.exe,.html,.txt)")
print ("Opening the file...")

mode = input ("w,r,r+ or a?")
if mode = "w":
writeToFile = open(fileName + w)
    fileName.write("sample text");
```

I want to use the write function with "w" but I cannot as it adds a w onto the end of the "fileName" variable as it is stored as a string, therefore it searches for a file with the letter w on the end i.e. test.pyw. Using python 3.5.2 by the way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"w"`, `"r"`, and friends are *file open modes*.

Your code appends these letters to the name of the file, as you point out. Do it this way:

```
writeToFile = open(fileName,w)
```

The mode is the second parameter of the `open()` call. Not something tacked on to the first parameter.

Comment: Okay, I understand this now, thank you so much! Good luck in the future man.

Comment: Sorry, new to stack overflow.